# app is launched for the first time being installed, controlling what form is shown. desktop net form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am in the process of writing my first C# application for my personal use. It is a utility app for my astrophotrophy hobby and I have reached the stage where I publish and install it on my personal desktop. But because this is a click once app, I have no clue where it is installed. So the first time the app launches, I want to have a form that will allow me to create the SQLite db wherever I want it.  Where I can find it. I also wish to change my reference entry/file which has my connection string to point to where I specify through the form. This will allow me to create backup and restore procedures for the db.

I am not sure how or where to place the code to accomplish the launch of this form.

Would it be in this event?

```
 public frm_AP_Utilities()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Or this event maybe?

```
 private void frm_AP_Utilities_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

I just did a little research and this sounds like a splash screen that would load as the first form created. But it offers no direction aw to how to do this after the app is created(my case).

Or would it just be easier to add another panel I can choose for pointing to a different folder for the db, and then modifying the reference for the connection string.

Comment: Do you want the database to be installed per-app or per-user?  Use one of the `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` folders (either `.ApplicationData` or `.CommonApplicationData`) as the place to do the install of the DB (create an _Astrophotrophy_ folder in one of those and stick it there).  You really don't want to be fishing out wherever Click-Once tucked your app away.  There's a reason they make it hard to find.  By the way, what is "astrophotrophy"?

Comment: Thank you, I will look those up.  I really don't care where the app is stored to be honest, just the db.

Comment: Can't spell, sorry.  It is Astrophotography. Imaging stars, nebula, star clusters, galaxies. Actually gets pretty technical with regard to equipment and the programs that I use.

Comment: Your application is installed in `Application.StartupPath`. Don't store / create your database there. Use, e.g., `Application.CommonAppDataPath` . See the other paths you can directly access using the `Application` object (AppData Local and Roaming folders of the User that installed the application). Also see:  [Access local and remote data in ClickOnce applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/accessing-local-and-remote-data-in-clickonce-applications)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I am going to use the 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); location for my data.  I found through a messagebox in the frm_AP_Utilities_Load event that this would be both perfect for my db and also where to put the logic to put the db there.   I also need to add some logic to load a table once a year in this db which I did not want the user to have to request.  So, this resolved a couple  of issues for me.  Again, thank you everyone for the replies

Comment: @OldAndRetired Hi, I posted your correct solution as the answer. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);` location for your data.

This code can get an example of a specific folder path.

When you call this method it will return a string representing the path to the application data folder.

Referenced from OldAndRetired